# Using svn with C# web projects - I need some tips

Tags: c#, svn, visual-web-developer

I have 2 solutions.
sln 1 - .net MVC c# project + 2 class libraries projects.
sln 2 - .net WCF c# project + 3 class libraries projects.
I want to share the code between 3 programmers.

My questions:

1. Should I put the 2 solutions in one repository?
2. Should I include the entire(!) solution in the repository?
   If i do so, every time I compile or even do something in my VS i get staff to commit.
   So if yes, what do i need to "add to ignore"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two projects then better to put the solutions separately.

Avoid adding bin and obj directories to SVN.

See a [codeproject article about setting SVN for ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Subversion.aspx) and [a Practical guide to subversion on Windows](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)

Also see [visualsvn guide](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00002/)